# How to pass a variable in Python sockets?

Tags: python, sockets, client-server

I have the python client application with the following code and it works fine:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', 55555))
sock.send(b'mkdir test') # windows command
data = sock.recv(1024)
sock.close()
print(data)
```

I need to input commands with input operator, e.g.:

```
comm = input('Input the system command: ') # mkdir test
sock.send(b'f{comm}')
```

But it doesn't work. I tried to change b to byte, wrote b'\f and like that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are trying it, if I'm right, you are trying to use `f` strings in an binary (`b`) string, but it can't be done. So instead, try this,

```
comm = input('Input the system command: ') # mkdir test
sock.send(b'{}'.format(comm, encoding='utf-8'))
```

This will help you achieve what you wanna do.

if that doesn't work, you can do this,

```
comm = input('Input the system command: ') # mkdir test
sock.send(bytes(comm, encoding='utf-8'))
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! I also added encoding to the code and have the following: sock.send(bytes(comm, encoding='utf8'))

Comment: @AlexLargman Yeah, that's great, and if this was what you wanted, just accept this answer so others know your problem had been solved